# Как докеризовать фронтенд-часть приложения на чистом js

Tags: javascript, python, docker, tornado

Есть бэкенд на tornado (python) и фронтенд на чистом js с использованием классов. Локально, без докера, этот бэкенд раздает статику используя относительную ссылку на папку с фронтендом (помимо приема данных с фронтенда). Собран докер-образ бэкенда. Какой базовый образ использовать для докер-образа фронтенда, чтобы у бэкенда был доступ к статике? Они должны быть в разных контейнерах (помимо них есть еще несколько сервисов - микросервисная архитектура). С докером никогда не работал, только начинаю, в интернете нашел информацию об образе на основе Node.js, но там и приложение бэкенда на express, либо фронтенд на React, то есть это не мой вариант. Еще нашел информацию про образ на основе nginx, но статику у меня раздает tornado, а не nginx, тоже, насколько я понял, не мой вариант. Может быть есть какой-то вариант доступа к папке фронтенда из другого контейнера - бэкенда, или ее можно скопировать в контейнер бэкенда при запуске?

Comment: фронтенд у вас грузится с tornado ?

Comment: Да, локально, без докера грузится.

Comment: В этом случае вам будет достаточно одного контейнера на базе  tornado
А какой  - вам решать. Можно попробовать docmosis/tornado

взят отсюда https://github.com/Docmosis/tornado-docker?ysclid=lcpx4c29d0192523027

Comment: Это тестовое задание, по его условию фронтенд тоже должен быть в контейнере.

Comment: Slava65 фронтенд не может существовать без web сервера, т.е. javascript и статика  и так будут в контейнере. Если же вам нужен отдельный контейнер для frontend, то его можно собрать на базе nginx, который будет отдавать статику с javascript. А по определенным путям будет вызываться tornado. То есть nginx будет выступать в роли proxy и перенаправлять запросы в tornado